# Rails or Node for web parser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, parsing, node.js

i want to build a parser, which parses multiple pages of an xml document. these pages include images and other media, which are served by an extra static asset server. now my question is:

should i use rails to parse the document or make a special node server, which does that? i thought about node because of the performance.

the parser creates a html document out of the xml file.

thanks in advance!

edit: these html pages get viewed from multiple users.

Comment: I would personally do it in Rails, since I am currently all in-love with rails, but the better solution is probably node.js :) Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it makes much of a difference if you can parse 100k pages per second with ruby or 200k pages per second with node.js unless you're parsing billions of xml documents (I made those numbers up). You should use the tools you're most familiar with.

However, there are some cool libaries for web scraping/parsing in node.js

- [You can use jQuery with node.js!](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs)
- [node.io - web scraper module, supports jquery, distributed processing, modules and more](https://github.com/chriso/node.io)
- [another node.js web scraper module - fetch pages in parallel, add rate limiting](https://github.com/mape/node-scraper)

Comment: and including the conversion from xml elements to html elements? so the performance regarding parsing + building? thanks

Comment: @Tronic while it's true that XML parsing is slow (compared to, say, JSON or yaml), you can still parse hundreds of thousands of XML files per second on a modern computer. I don't think you should be worrying about performance

Comment: so an asynchronous approach wouldn't have much effect in terms of parsing performance? thanks!

Comment: @Tronic node.js is single-threaded, meaning it can only parse one document at a time (it's a cpu bound task). What node.js excels at, is downloading pages in parallel and parsing them (or serving them to the clients) while waiting for another download to finish i.e. it doesn't block on i/o bound tasks.

Comment: This explains how node.js works http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/ or http://www.beakkon.com/geek/node.js/why-node.js-single-thread-event-loop-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'd  use node because rails seems a little overkill for this. However if you're more familiar w/ ruby instead of rails you should do it w/ Sinatra or any  other smaller framework. Simply my point is that rails is over kill for this.